# Filtering rows by date in a full outer join query -> missing some results

Tags: mysql, where-clause, full-outer-join

### Background

I've got two tables with different types of feedback items in MySQL. I've built a query to combine these tables by `FULL OUTER JOIN` (which is actually written as two joins and an union in MySQL) and to count some average grades. This query seems to work perfectly:

```
  (SELECT name, AVG(l.overallQuality) AS avgLingQual,
    AVG(s.overallSatisfaction) AS avgSvcQual
  FROM feedback_linguistic AS l
  LEFT JOIN feedback_service AS s USING(name)
  GROUP BY name)
UNION ALL
  (SELECT name, AVG(l.overallQuality) AS avgLingQual, 
    AVG(s.overallSatisfaction) AS avgSvcQual
  FROM feedback_linguistic AS l
  RIGHT JOIN feedback_service AS s USING(name)
  WHERE l.id IS NULL
  GROUP BY name)
ORDER BY name;
```

(This is somewhat simplified for readability but it doesn't make a difference here)

### Problem

Next I tried adding filtering by date (i.e. only feedback items created after a certain date are taken in account). With my SQL skills and the research I did, I was able to come up with this:

```
  (SELECT name, AVG(l.overallQuality) AS avgLingQual,
    AVG(s.overallSatisfaction) AS avgSvcQual
  FROM feedback_linguistic AS l
  LEFT JOIN feedback_service AS s USING(name)
  WHERE (s.createdTime >= '" & date & "' OR s.createdTime IS NULL)
    AND (l.createdTime >= '" & date & "' OR l.createdTime IS NULL)
  GROUP BY name)
UNION ALL
  (SELECT name, AVG(l.overallQuality) AS avgLingQual, 
    AVG(s.overallSatisfaction) AS avgSvcQual
  FROM feedback_linguistic AS l
  RIGHT JOIN feedback_service AS s USING(name)
  WHERE l.id IS NULL
    AND (s.createdTime >= '" & date & "' OR s.createdTime IS NULL)
  GROUP BY name)
ORDER BY name;
```

This *almost* works: the results I get look about right. However, a couple of feedback items are missing. For example, setting the date one month ago, I counted feedback for 21 different people in the database, but this query only returns 19 people. The worst thing is that I can't seem to find any similarities between the missing items.

Am I doing something wrong in this query? I think that the `WHERE` clause does the date filtering after the `JOIN` and ideally I would probably be doing it before. Then again, I don't know if this causes my problem and I also have no idea how to write this query differently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A full outer join is a combination of 3 joins:

1- inner join between A and B
2- left exclusion join between A and B
3- right exclusion join between A and B

Note that the combination of an inner and a left exclusion join is a left outer join, so you normally rewrite the query as a `left outer join` + `right exclusion join`.
However for debugging purposes it can be useful to `union` all 3 joins and to add some marker as to which join does what:

```
  /*inner join*/
  (SELECT
     'inner' as join_type 
     , COALESCE(s.name, l.name) as listname
     , AVG(l.overallQuality) AS avgLingQual
     , AVG(s.overallSatisfaction) AS avgSvcQual 
  FROM feedback_linguistic l 
  INNER JOIN feedback_service s ON (l.name = s.name) 
  WHERE (s.createdTime >= '" & date & "' OR s.createdTime IS NULL) 
    AND (l.createdTime >= '" & date & "' OR l.createdTime IS NULL) 
  GROUP BY l.name) 
UNION ALL
  (SELECT
     'left exclusion' as join_type 
     , COALESCE(s.name, l.name) as listname
     , AVG(l.overallQuality) AS avgLingQual
     , AVG(s.overallSatisfaction) AS avgSvcQual 
  FROM feedback_linguistic l 
  LEFT JOIN feedback_service s ON (l.name = s.name) 
  WHERE s.id IS NULL
    /*AND (s.createdTime >= '" & date & "' OR s.createdTime IS NULL) */
    AND (l.createdTime >= '" & date & "' OR l.createdTime IS NULL) 
  GROUP BY l.name) 
UNION ALL
  (SELECT 
     'right exclusion' as join_type
     , COALESCE(s.name, l.name) as listname
     , AVG(l.overallQuality) AS avgLingQual 
     , AVG(s.overallSatisfaction) AS avgSvcQual 
  FROM feedback_linguistic l 
  RIGHT JOIN feedback_service s ON (s.name = l.name) 
  WHERE l.id IS NULL
    AND (s.createdTime >= '" & date & "' OR s.createdTime IS NULL) 
    /*AND (l.createdTime >= '" & date & "' OR l.createdTime IS NULL) */
  GROUP BY s.name) 
ORDER BY listname;
```

> I think that the WHERE clause does the date filtering after the JOIN and ideally I would probably be doing it before.

If you want to do the filtering before, then put it in the join clause.

Comment: Thanks, now I understand the full outer join better and even learned something new about SQL. I didn't think of using coalesce with the names and had trouble using JOIN ON instead of JOIN USING...

Answer (score 2):

I accepted Johans answer as he did a good job explaining this stuff to me and the answer is useful even in a more generic sense. However, I thought I'd also post the first solution I arrived to. It was using subqueries:

```
  (SELECT name, AVG(l.overallQuality) AS avgLingQual,
    AVG(s.overallSatisfaction) AS avgSvcQual
  FROM (
    SELECT * FROM feedback_linguistic WHERE createdTime >= '" & date & "'
  ) AS l
  LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT * FROM feedback_service WHERE createdTime >= '" & date & "'
  ) AS s USING(name)
  GROUP BY name)
UNION ALL
  (SELECT name, AVG(l.overallQuality) AS avgLingQual, 
    AVG(s.overallSatisfaction) AS avgSvcQual
  FROM (
    SELECT * FROM feedback_linguistic WHERE createdTime >= '" & date & "'
  ) AS l
  RIGHT JOIN (
    SELECT * FROM feedback_service WHERE createdTime >= '" & date & "'
  ) AS s USING(name)
  WHERE l.id IS NULL
  GROUP BY name)
ORDER BY name;
```

The results are correct with this query. However, the solution doesn't really look optimal, as subqueries are sometimes slow in my experience. Then again, I haven't done any performance analysis, so maybe using subqueries here is not a bottleneck. In any case it worked fast enough in my application.

Comment: You can use `explain select` to see the query plan.